# Can't understand what's went wrong

Tags: javascript

I wrote this code as a practice for Factory Pattern but getting errors & I dunno why.

Code:

```
class ShopFactory {
    constructor (item, type, name) {
        let shelf;
        if(type === "toiletries"){
            shelf = new Toiletries(item, name);
        }else if (type === "cosmetics") {
            shelf = new Cosmetics(item, name);
        }else if (type === "foods") {
            shelf = new Foods(item, name);
        }else if (type === "beautifications"){
            shelf = new Beautifications(item, name);
        }
        shelf.type = type;
        shelf.func = function () {
            console.log(`${this.item}--${this.type}--${this.name} Cost: ${this.cost}`);
        }
        return shelf;
    }
}

class Toiletries{
    constructor (item, name){
        this.item = item;
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = "$15";
    }
}
class Cosmetics{
    constructor (item, name){
        this.item = item;
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = "$30";
    }
}
class Foods{
    constructor (item, name){
        this.item = item;
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = "$20";
    }
}
class Beautifications{
    constructor (item, name){
        this.item = item;
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = "$25";
    }
}

var shelves = [];
shelves.push(new ShopFactory("grocery","foods","rice"));
shelves.push(new ShopFactory("cleaning","toiletries","toilet-cleaner"));
shelves.push(new ShopFactory("machine-tools","beautifications","screw-driver"));
shelves.push(new ShopFactory("powder","Cosmetics","body-powder"));
shelves.push(new ShopFactory("cleaning","beautifications","wand"));
shelves.push(new ShopFactory("grocery","foods","fish"));

console.log(shelves);
```

```
Error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of undefined
    at ShopFactory.createShelf (app2.js:18)
    at app2.js:60
createShelf @ app2.js:18
(anonymous) @ app2.js:60
```

Comment: You have `let shelf;` but it never gets assigned, so it's still `undefined`.  Log `type` and you'll see why.

Comment: Why do you use a class that only uses a constructor? Would it not be easier to use a regular function?

Comment: it fails at `"Cosmetics"` because this value is not equal to any of the ones you test for. shelf ends up as undefined, and undefined.type is a crash situation. Try `"cosmetics"` or add handling to ignore case.

Comment: your script fails when u pass "Cosmetics" as type and you check for "cosmetics" case-sensitive! 


in this case shelf is not an object and u cant add properties

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I know but I am learning...

Comment: @john-smith, so I know what is the root cause of not working. You actually showed me the right cause. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is: what will the factory do if you pass it an invalid `type`, e.g. `"Cosmetics"`? *Remember that caps matter.* You should throw a proper informative error, otherwise `shelf` won't be set and you're trying to do `(undefined).type = type;`:

```js
class ShopFactory {
    constructor(item, type, name) {
        let shelf;
        if (type === "toiletries") {
            shelf = new Toiletries(item, name);
        } else if (type === "cosmetics") {
            shelf = new Cosmetics(item, name);
        } else if (type === "foods") {
            shelf = new Foods(item, name);
        } else if (type === "beautifications") {
            shelf = new Beautifications(item, name);
        } else {
            throw new Error(`Unknown type '${type}'`);
        }
        shelf.type = type;
        shelf.func = function () {
            console.log(`${this.item}--${this.type}--${this.name} Cost: ${this.cost}`);
        }
        return shelf;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

shelves should be object since you're attaching `type` on it.

```
class ShopFactory {
    constructor (item, type, name) {
        let shelf = {};
        if(type === "toiletries"){
            shelf = new Toiletries(item, name);
        }else if (type === "cosmetics") {
            shelf = new Cosmetics(item, name);
        }else if (type === "foods") {
            shelf = new Foods(item, name);
        }else if (type === "beautifications"){
            shelf = new Beautifications(item, name);
        }
        shelf.type = type;
        shelf.func = function () {
            console.log(`${this.item}--${this.type}--${this.name} Cost: ${this.cost}`);
        }
        return shelf;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are executing this line

```
shelves.push(new ShopFactory("powder","Cosmetics","body-powder"));
```

this below clause of your Constructor fails ( Becuase in the conditions "Cosmetics" doesn't matches) so the variable `shelf` is still undefined. Then you assigned `shelf.type` but as the variable `shelf` is still undefined(not an object), you can't assign a property on it. That's why you are getting the error.

```
    if(type === "toiletries"){
        shelf = new Toiletries(item, name);
    }else if (type === "cosmetics") {
        shelf = new Cosmetics(item, name);
    }else if (type === "foods") {
        shelf = new Foods(item, name);
    }else if (type === "beautifications"){
        shelf = new Beautifications(item, name);
    }
```

One quick solution would be declaring variable `shelf` as an object like `let shelf = {};`